# Serving static resources with relative paths in Clojure to different routes

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm building off of the `lein new compojure-app` template. I've got a route to `/` which works fine, as well as a route to `/foo/` that works. Between the two pages, only the body changes, so I would like to stick as much as I can into a common view function (I'm using the default `common` in `views/layout.clj`). However, when serving resources by relative path, like `css/main.css`, my route to `/` works fine, but the route to `/foo/` is looking for `/foo/css/main.css` instead of looking in the root directory. How do I serve static resources with relative paths to arbitrary routes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`wrap-base-url`](http://weavejester.github.io/hiccup/hiccup.middleware.html#var-wrap-base-url) middleware along with [`include-css`](http://weavejester.github.io/hiccup/hiccup.page.html#var-include-css). The `wrap-base-url` will set [`*base-url*`](http://weavejester.github.io/hiccup/hiccup.util.html#var-*base-url*) dynamic var which will be used to construct URLs for resources included with `include-css`, `include-js` or by using `to-url` directly.

If you deploy your app as a war in a servlet container, `wrap-base-url` will autodetect your app root context (e.g. `/my-app/`). Otherwise you need to provide it the root path manually as the second argument.

Comment: A little more clarity: The string passed to `include-css` must begin with a `/`. In other words, don't do this: `(include-css "css/main.css")`. Instead, do this: `(include-css "/css/main.css")`. Subtle, but it's the difference between working and not.